# How is an electric field inside the wire? How is it produced?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

let complete circuit with  a battery .
How is an electric field inside the wire ? How is it produced ? Where is the source of the electric field  ? Why is it along the wire?

Answer (score 0):

The field is produced, like the battery voltage difference, by a chemical reaction.
There is an electric field outside a charged battery, see http://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?t=65666 , especially the last post.
When you connect the terminals via a resistor, charges rearrange so that the voltage drop is only across the resistor. Consequently there is an electric field around and inside the resistor. The latter is driving the electrons .